# Handle a check box form without a submit button?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I'm creating a check list and I need some help coming up with the best way to handle this task.  I want to avoid using a "Submit" button, and have the box update the database at the time of click.  The code simply grabs the ID of the div and sends it to the post page.  It also changes the check box div from unchecked to checked.

The code works, but the issue I'm having is when someone clicks through the list of 30+ items quickly, it lags the database and many actions aren't recorded.  Does anyone have any ideas to what is the best way to handle this so I can accomplish the desired effect without using a submit form button?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question_check_box").click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('question_check_box').addClass('question_checked_box');
        var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("at_post.jsp", {pass: "1", check: "1", id: "${param.id}", update_q: question_id});
    });
});
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Ya - do what every other normal programmer would ever do, place a submit button or link at the bottom of the page and only db call ONCE.  I don't know why you don't want that..if you don't want a button you can use a hyperlink or an image link or anything.

Answer (score 0):

On click of a checkbox you could disable all other form elements on the screen. Add a callback to your post that, on success of the post, will re-enable all of the form elements.

I've done this several times in the past in different ways. You could literally disable the elements to prevent the user from clicking on them. Sometimes it's nice for the user to have some feedback, so even changing the cursor to a loading cursor can work for desktop views. Perhaps have a small rotating loading icon beside the clicked field that disappears on success of the post, this may work better for mobile users. 
You could take it further and have an overlay on the page with some sort of loading icon, however, this may be overkill if the request only takes a second or less. You could, however, have a transparent overlay that blocks clicks to the page behind. This might be easier to implement than disabling all of the elements on the page, and will prevent the user from being able to click on nav items etc. 
You could implement a click handler that intercepts all clicks on the document, but only have this active on click of a checkbox, then disable it on the success callback from the post.

Nothing too difficult there that a quick Google search won't unearth. I do recommend blocking requests until you get a callback from your post though.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is obviously not trivial which is why every developer and their mother loves the submit button. That said, here is one idea I have.

First of all, I wouldn't tie the `$.post` directly to the checkbox click. Instead I would wait for more changes to happen and submit all the changes in one request. For example, start a timer on the first click to indicate a change has happened. Wait a few seconds and submit once the timer has expired. If they make another change before the timer expires, start the wait time over again. Here is a rough idea:

```
var timer;
var question_ids = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question_check_box").click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('question_check_box').addClass('question_checked_box');

        //add question to list of questions were going to change
        var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
        question_ids.push(question_id);
        startTimer();
    });
});

function startTimer() {
    //remove previous timer so request is not made to server
    clearTimeout(timer); 
    //wait 5 seconds before submission to server
    timer = setTimeout(endTimer, 5000); 
}

function endTimer() {
    //this post will need to change so that multiple questions can be submitted at one time
    //consider disabling input while request is in progress
    $.post("at_post.jsp", {pass: "1", check: "1", id: "${param.id}", update_q: question_id});

    //upon success clear question_ids
    //question_ids = [];
    ...

}
```

You will run into the same problem again if the user decides to make further changes while the save is in progress, so consider disallowing changes while the save is in progress.

This approach can be problematic if the user is likely to leave the page quickly upon making their changes. So if you go with this approach, make sure the user knows their data is saving and/or has been saved. You would also need to discourage the user from leaving the page via the back button or simply by closing the browser.

Best of luck!